# Background Shading in Histogram3D

Tags: plotting, histograms

I am preparing some data for dissemination. I have a series of plots that look like so, using `ListLinePlot`:

[image]

The background shading is just being added using *Mathematica*'s drawing tools. However, the following visualization (a 3D Histogram) does not offer similar functionality.

Here is the dataset that I am using (I apologize for the length, but hopefully the code box is OK):

```
dataHistogramSet = {{{1997, 0}, {1997, 0}, {1997, 0}, {1997, 
     0}, {1997, 0}, {1997, 2}, {1997, 0}, {1997, 0}, {1997, 0}, {1997,
      0}, {1997, 0}, {1997, 0}, {1997, 0}, {1997, 0}, {1997, 
     0}, {1997, 0}, {1997, 0}, {1997, 0}, {1997, 0}, {1997, 0}, {1997,
      0}, {1997, 0}, {1997, 0}, {1997, 0}, {1997, 0}, {1997, 
     0}, {1997, 1}, {1997, 0}, {1997, 0}, {1997, 0}, {1997, 0}, {1997,
      0}, {1997, 16}, {1997, 0}, {1997, 1}, {1997, 0}, {1997, 
     0}, {1997, 0}, {1997, 5}, {1997, 0}, {1997, 5}, {1997, 0}, {1997,
      0}, {1997, 5}, {1997, 0}, {1997, 0}, {1997, 0}, {1997, 
     0}, {1997, 0}, {1997, 0}, {1997, 0}, {1997, 0}, {1997, 0}, {1997,
      0}, {1997, 0}, {1997, 0}, {1997, 0}, {1997, 0}, {1997, 
     0}, {1997, 2}, {1997, 0}, {1997, 0}, {1997, 3}, {1997, 0}, {1997,
      0}, {1997, 6}, {1997, 0}, {1997, 1}, {1997, 0}, {1997, 
     0}, {1997, 4}, {1997, 0}, {1997, 0}, {1997, 0}, {1997, 
     62}, {1997, 0}, {1997, 0}, {1997, 0}, {1997, 1}, {1997, 
     0}, {1997, 0}, {1997, 0}, {1997, 0}, {1997, 0}, {1997, 0}, {1997,
      0}, {1997, 0}}, {{1998, 0}, {1998, 0}, {1998, 0}, {1998, 
     0}, {1998, 0}, {1998, 0}, {1998, 1}, {1998, 19}, {1998, 
     0}, {1998, 0}, {1998, 0}, {1998, 0}, {1998, 0}, {1998, 0}, {1998,
      0}, {1998, 0}, {1998, 0}, {1998, 0}, {1998, 0}, {1998, 
     0}, {1998, 0}, {1998, 1}, {1998, 32}, {1998, 0}, {1998, 
     0}, {1998, 0}, {1998, 0}, {1998, 6}, {1998, 1}, {1998, 2}, {1998,
      0}, {1998, 0}, {1998, 0}, {1998, 0}, {1998, 0}, {1998, 
     0}, {1998, 0}, {1998, 0}, {1998, 0}, {1998, 3}, {1998, 0}, {1998,
      0}, {1998, 1}, {1998, 0}, {1998, 0}, {1998, 0}, {1998, 
     0}, {1998, 2}, {1998, 0}, {1998, 0}, {1998, 0}, {1998, 0}, {1998,
      0}, {1998, 0}, {1998, 2}, {1998, 0}, {1998, 0}, {1998, 
     0}, {1998, 0}, {1998, 0}, {1998, 0}, {1998, 0}, {1998, 0}, {1998,
      0}, {1998, 1}, {1998, 0}, {1998, 3}}, {{1999, 0}, {1999, 
     0}, {1999, 0}, {1999, 0}, {1999, 0}, {1999, 0}, {1999, 0}, {1999,
      0}, {1999, 0}, {1999, 0}, {1999, 3}, {1999, 0}, {1999, 
     82}, {1999, 0}, {1999, 0}, {1999, 0}, {1999, 7}, {1999, 
     0}, {1999, 0}, {1999, 25}, {1999, 9}, {1999, 0}, {1999, 
     0}, {1999, 0}, {1999, 20}, {1999, 0}, {1999, 0}, {1999, 
     0}, {1999, 0}, {1999, 0}, {1999, 0}, {1999, 0}, {1999, 0}, {1999,
      0}, {1999, 1}, {1999, 0}, {1999, 0}, {1999, 0}, {1999, 
     0}, {1999, 0}, {1999, 0}, {1999, 0}, {1999, 0}, {1999, 
     33}, {1999, 0}, {1999, 0}, {1999, 23}, {1999, 0}, {1999, 
     0}, {1999, 0}, {1999, 60}, {1999, 0}, {1999, 11}, {1999, 
     0}, {1999, 0}, {1999, 0}, {1999, 0}, {1999, 0}, {1999, 0}, {1999,
      0}, {1999, 0}, {1999, 0}, {1999, 0}, {1999, 0}, {1999, 
     0}, {1999, 0}, {1999, 0}, {1999, 3}, {1999, 0}, {1999, 3}, {1999,
      0}, {1999, 0}, {1999, 0}, {1999, 0}, {1999, 2}, {1999, 
     2}, {1999, 0}, {1999, 0}, {1999, 0}, {1999, 0}, {1999, 0}, {1999,
      0}, {1999, 0}}, {{2000, 0}, {2000, 0}, {2000, 0}, {2000, 
     0}, {2000, 0}, {2000, 0}, {2000, 254}, {2000, 4}, {2000, 
     0}, {2000, 0}, {2000, 0}, {2000, 0}, {2000, 8}, {2000, 0}, {2000,
      0}, {2000, 14}, {2000, 0}, {2000, 0}, {2000, 12}, {2000, 
     72}, {2000, 0}, {2000, 0}, {2000, 0}, {2000, 0}, {2000, 
     0}, {2000, 0}, {2000, 4}, {2000, 0}, {2000, 0}, {2000, 0}, {2000,
      0}, {2000, 0}, {2000, 22}, {2000, 0}, {2000, 0}, {2000, 
     0}, {2000, 0}, {2000, 0}, {2000, 0}, {2000, 0}, {2000, 0}, {2000,
      2}, {2000, 0}, {2000, 0}, {2000, 0}, {2000, 0}, {2000, 
     0}, {2000, 0}, {2000, 0}, {2000, 0}, {2000, 0}, {2000, 8}, {2000,
      0}, {2000, 0}, {2000, 0}, {2000, 0}, {2000, 0}, {2000, 
     8}, {2000, 0}, {2000, 0}, {2000, 0}, {2000, 0}, {2000, 0}, {2000,
      0}, {2000, 0}, {2000, 0}, {2000, 0}, {2000, 0}, {2000, 
     0}}, {{2001, 0}, {2001, 5}, {2001, 3}, {2001, 0}, {2001, 
     0}, {2001, 23}, {2001, 0}, {2001, 0}, {2001, 1}, {2001, 
     0}, {2001, 0}, {2001, 0}, {2001, 0}, {2001, 4}, {2001, 
     13}, {2001, 0}, {2001, 0}, {2001, 0}, {2001, 0}, {2001, 
     0}, {2001, 0}, {2001, 0}, {2001, 0}, {2001, 0}, {2001, 0}, {2001,
      0}, {2001, 0}, {2001, 16}, {2001, 0}, {2001, 0}, {2001, 
     0}, {2001, 23}, {2001, 0}, {2001, 4}, {2001, 0}, {2001, 
     0}, {2001, 0}, {2001, 9}, {2001, 0}, {2001, 0}, {2001, 0}, {2001,
      0}, {2001, 1}, {2001, 0}, {2001, 3}, {2001, 5}, {2001, 
     0}, {2001, 28}, {2001, 0}, {2001, 0}, {2001, 0}, {2001, 
     0}, {2001, 10}, {2001, 0}, {2001, 0}, {2001, 0}, {2001, 
     71}, {2001, 0}, {2001, 0}, {2001, 51}, {2001, 2}, {2001, 
     0}, {2001, 0}, {2001, 0}, {2001, 0}, {2001, 0}, {2001, 0}, {2001,
      0}, {2001, 0}, {2001, 0}, {2001, 0}, {2001, 0}, {2001, 
     0}}, {{2002, 0}, {2002, 0}, {2002, 0}, {2002, 0}, {2002, 
     0}, {2002, 0}, {2002, 0}, {2002, 0}, {2002, 6}, {2002, 0}, {2002,
      0}, {2002, 0}, {2002, 0}, {2002, 0}, {2002, 0}, {2002, 
     26}, {2002, 0}, {2002, 0}, {2002, 0}, {2002, 0}, {2002, 
     0}, {2002, 0}, {2002, 0}, {2002, 0}, {2002, 0}, {2002, 0}, {2002,
      0}, {2002, 2}, {2002, 0}, {2002, 0}, {2002, 0}, {2002, 
     0}, {2002, 21}, {2002, 0}, {2002, 15}, {2002, 0}, {2002, 
     0}, {2002, 0}, {2002, 0}, {2002, 0}, {2002, 0}, {2002, 0}, {2002,
      5}, {2002, 1}, {2002, 0}, {2002, 0}, {2002, 0}, {2002, 
     0}, {2002, 0}, {2002, 0}, {2002, 0}, {2002, 0}, {2002, 0}, {2002,
      0}, {2002, 3}, {2002, 0}, {2002, 0}, {2002, 0}, {2002, 
     0}, {2002, 0}, {2002, 0}, {2002, 0}, {2002, 0}, {2002, 0}, {2002,
      0}, {2002, 5}, {2002, 0}, {2002, 2}, {2002, 1}, {2002, 
     1}, {2002, 0}, {2002, 0}, {2002, 0}, {2002, 0}, {2002, 0}, {2002,
      0}, {2002, 0}, {2002, 2}}, {{2003, 0}, {2003, 1}, {2003, 
     0}, {2003, 0}, {2003, 15}, {2003, 0}, {2003, 0}, {2003, 
     0}, {2003, 18}, {2003, 0}, {2003, 0}, {2003, 2}, {2003, 
     0}, {2003, 0}, {2003, 6}, {2003, 0}, {2003, 0}, {2003, 0}, {2003,
      0}, {2003, 6}, {2003, 0}, {2003, 0}, {2003, 0}, {2003, 
     98}, {2003, 0}, {2003, 11}, {2003, 0}, {2003, 0}, {2003, 
     0}, {2003, 2}, {2003, 4}, {2003, 0}, {2003, 0}, {2003, 3}, {2003,
      1}, {2003, 15}, {2003, 3}, {2003, 0}, {2003, 0}, {2003, 
     0}, {2003, 5}, {2003, 0}, {2003, 0}, {2003, 0}, {2003, 0}, {2003,
      26}, {2003, 0}, {2003, 0}, {2003, 0}, {2003, 0}, {2003, 
     0}, {2003, 1}, {2003, 0}, {2003, 0}, {2003, 4}, {2003, 0}, {2003,
      0}, {2003, 0}, {2003, 19}, {2003, 1}, {2003, 0}, {2003, 
     0}, {2003, 0}, {2003, 6}, {2003, 0}, {2003, 0}, {2003, 0}, {2003,
      0}, {2003, 0}, {2003, 0}, {2003, 0}, {2003, 0}, {2003, 
     0}, {2003, 4}, {2003, 0}, {2003, 0}, {2003, 0}, {2003, 0}, {2003,
      0}, {2003, 0}, {2003, 0}, {2003, 0}, {2003, 0}, {2003, 
     0}, {2003, 0}, {2003, 0}, {2003, 0}, {2003, 0}, {2003, 
     7}}, {{2004, 0}, {2004, 0}, {2004, 0}, {2004, 0}, {2004, 
     0}, {2004, 0}, {2004, 0}, {2004, 0}, {2004, 0}, {2004, 
     30}, {2004, 0}, {2004, 0}, {2004, 0}, {2004, 0}, {2004, 
     0}, {2004, 0}, {2004, 0}, {2004, 0}, {2004, 6}, {2004, 
     20}, {2004, 0}, {2004, 0}, {2004, 0}, {2004, 0}, {2004, 
     0}, {2004, 0}, {2004, 4}, {2004, 0}, {2004, 0}, {2004, 0}, {2004,
      2}, {2004, 0}, {2004, 0}, {2004, 1}, {2004, 0}, {2004, 
     2}, {2004, 0}, {2004, 0}, {2004, 2}, {2004, 0}, {2004, 
     46}, {2004, 6}, {2004, 0}, {2004, 0}, {2004, 0}, {2004, 
     107}, {2004, 0}, {2004, 1}, {2004, 0}, {2004, 0}, {2004, 
     0}, {2004, 1}, {2004, 5}, {2004, 0}, {2004, 0}, {2004, 0}, {2004,
      0}, {2004, 5}, {2004, 0}, {2004, 0}, {2004, 0}, {2004, 
     0}, {2004, 0}, {2004, 8}, {2004, 0}}, {{2005, 0}, {2005, 
     0}, {2005, 0}, {2005, 6}, {2005, 0}, {2005, 0}, {2005, 0}, {2005,
      4}, {2005, 0}, {2005, 0}, {2005, 0}, {2005, 23}, {2005, 
     140}, {2005, 0}, {2005, 1}, {2005, 1}, {2005, 0}, {2005, 
     0}, {2005, 0}, {2005, 0}, {2005, 0}, {2005, 0}, {2005, 2}, {2005,
      0}, {2005, 0}, {2005, 0}, {2005, 0}, {2005, 0}, {2005, 
     0}, {2005, 13}, {2005, 0}, {2005, 2}, {2005, 0}, {2005, 
     9}, {2005, 0}, {2005, 0}, {2005, 0}, {2005, 0}, {2005, 0}, {2005,
      2}, {2005, 5}, {2005, 0}, {2005, 9}, {2005, 2}, {2005, 
     2}, {2005, 0}, {2005, 4}, {2005, 0}, {2005, 16}, {2005, 
     0}, {2005, 7}, {2005, 0}, {2005, 0}, {2005, 3}, {2005, 0}, {2005,
      0}, {2005, 0}, {2005, 1}, {2005, 0}, {2005, 0}, {2005, 
     3}, {2005, 0}, {2005, 0}, {2005, 0}, {2005, 3}, {2005, 
     71}, {2005, 0}, {2005, 0}, {2005, 0}, {2005, 0}, {2005, 
     0}}, {{2006, 0}, {2006, 0}, {2006, 0}, {2006, 0}, {2006, 
     0}, {2006, 4}, {2006, 15}, {2006, 7}, {2006, 2}, {2006, 
     1}, {2006, 0}, {2006, 0}, {2006, 3}, {2006, 0}, {2006, 0}, {2006,
      0}, {2006, 0}, {2006, 0}, {2006, 0}, {2006, 2}, {2006, 
     9}, {2006, 0}, {2006, 0}, {2006, 0}, {2006, 0}, {2006, 
     97}, {2006, 0}, {2006, 4}, {2006, 0}, {2006, 0}, {2006, 
     0}, {2006, 0}, {2006, 0}, {2006, 0}, {2006, 0}, {2006, 0}, {2006,
      1}, {2006, 0}, {2006, 0}, {2006, 0}, {2006, 1}, {2006, 
     0}, {2006, 0}, {2006, 0}, {2006, 1}, {2006, 1}, {2006, 0}, {2006,
      0}, {2006, 6}, {2006, 0}, {2006, 1}, {2006, 1}, {2006, 
     8}, {2006, 0}, {2006, 0}, {2006, 0}, {2006, 0}, {2006, 2}, {2006,
      0}, {2006, 0}, {2006, 0}, {2006, 0}, {2006, 0}, {2006, 
     0}, {2006, 5}, {2006, 0}, {2006, 3}, {2006, 0}, {2006, 
     25}}, {{2007, 0}, {2007, 0}, {2007, 0}, {2007, 0}, {2007, 
     6}, {2007, 0}, {2007, 0}, {2007, 0}, {2007, 2}, {2007, 0}, {2007,
      0}, {2007, 254}, {2007, 0}, {2007, 81}, {2007, 0}, {2007, 
     0}, {2007, 0}, {2007, 2}, {2007, 6}, {2007, 18}, {2007, 
     0}, {2007, 0}, {2007, 21}, {2007, 20}, {2007, 0}, {2007, 
     0}, {2007, 7}, {2007, 0}, {2007, 0}, {2007, 0}, {2007, 6}, {2007,
      5}, {2007, 0}, {2007, 0}, {2007, 0}, {2007, 1}, {2007, 
     2}, {2007, 0}, {2007, 0}, {2007, 11}, {2007, 0}, {2007, 
     0}, {2007, 0}, {2007, 2}, {2007, 7}, {2007, 0}, {2007, 0}, {2007,
      5}, {2007, 3}, {2007, 0}, {2007, 0}, {2007, 0}, {2007, 
     0}, {2007, 0}, {2007, 0}, {2007, 0}, {2007, 0}, {2007, 0}, {2007,
      0}, {2007, 0}, {2007, 0}, {2007, 3}, {2007, 0}}, {{2008, 
     0}, {2008, 0}, {2008, 166}, {2008, 10}, {2008, 0}, {2008, 
     0}, {2008, 0}, {2008, 0}, {2008, 12}, {2008, 0}, {2008, 
     0}, {2008, 0}, {2008, 30}, {2008, 0}, {2008, 0}, {2008, 
     14}, {2008, 0}, {2008, 0}, {2008, 0}, {2008, 0}, {2008, 
     0}, {2008, 0}, {2008, 0}, {2008, 2}, {2008, 0}, {2008, 0}, {2008,
      0}, {2008, 4}, {2008, 0}, {2008, 0}, {2008, 0}, {2008, 
     0}, {2008, 0}, {2008, 0}, {2008, 48}, {2008, 0}, {2008, 
     0}, {2008, 6}, {2008, 0}, {2008, 0}, {2008, 0}, {2008, 0}, {2008,
      0}, {2008, 0}, {2008, 2}, {2008, 4}, {2008, 0}, {2008, 
     0}, {2008, 0}, {2008, 0}, {2008, 0}, {2008, 194}, {2008, 
     0}, {2008, 10}, {2008, 218}, {2008, 0}, {2008, 20}, {2008, 
     0}, {2008, 8}, {2008, 2}, {2008, 0}, {2008, 24}, {2008, 
     34}, {2008, 0}, {2008, 0}, {2008, 22}, {2008, 4}, {2008, 
     0}}, {{2009, 1}, {2009, 0}, {2009, 0}, {2009, 0}, {2009, 
     2}, {2009, 0}, {2009, 2}, {2009, 1}, {2009, 2}, {2009, 0}, {2009,
      13}, {2009, 0}, {2009, 0}, {2009, 0}, {2009, 95}, {2009, 
     12}, {2009, 1}, {2009, 0}, {2009, 1}, {2009, 0}, {2009, 
     0}, {2009, 0}, {2009, 13}, {2009, 0}, {2009, 3}, {2009, 
     0}, {2009, 0}, {2009, 0}, {2009, 0}, {2009, 0}, {2009, 0}, {2009,
      0}, {2009, 0}, {2009, 0}, {2009, 0}, {2009, 0}, {2009, 
     6}, {2009, 2}, {2009, 2}, {2009, 19}, {2009, 0}, {2009, 
     0}, {2009, 0}, {2009, 1}, {2009, 6}, {2009, 0}, {2009, 0}, {2009,
      48}, {2009, 4}, {2009, 81}, {2009, 26}, {2009, 0}, {2009, 
     0}, {2009, 0}, {2009, 34}, {2009, 133}, {2009, 0}, {2009, 
     0}, {2009, 0}, {2009, 11}, {2009, 0}, {2009, 1}, {2009, 
     0}, {2009, 0}, {2009, 0}, {2009, 6}, {2009, 19}, {2009, 
     0}, {2009, 0}, {2009, 0}}, {{2010, 0}, {2010, 17}, {2010, 
     0}, {2010, 0}, {2010, 12}, {2010, 0}, {2010, 0}, {2010, 
     32}, {2010, 0}, {2010, 2}, {2010, 1}, {2010, 0}, {2010, 
     47}, {2010, 0}, {2010, 0}, {2010, 0}, {2010, 14}, {2010, 
     0}, {2010, 0}, {2010, 3}, {2010, 0}, {2010, 3}, {2010, 
     185}, {2010, 0}, {2010, 225}, {2010, 0}, {2010, 0}, {2010, 
     0}, {2010, 7}, {2010, 0}, {2010, 0}, {2010, 0}, {2010, 9}, {2010,
      0}, {2010, 0}, {2010, 0}, {2010, 0}, {2010, 2}, {2010, 
     9}, {2010, 15}, {2010, 119}, {2010, 0}, {2010, 0}, {2010, 
     0}, {2010, 5}, {2010, 0}, {2010, 0}, {2010, 0}, {2010, 0}, {2010,
      0}, {2010, 35}, {2010, 0}, {2010, 1}, {2010, 0}, {2010, 
     0}, {2010, 0}, {2010, 0}, {2010, 0}, {2010, 5}, {2010, 0}, {2010,
      1}, {2010, 4}, {2010, 0}, {2010, 0}, {2010, 0}, {2010, 
     0}, {2010, 0}, {2010, 0}, {2010, 0}}};
```

and the command:

```
Histogram3D[dataHistogramSet, FaceGrids -> {Bottom, Front, Left}, 
ChartStyle -> "GrayTones", ViewPoint -> {2.78, 1.3, 1.43}, 
PlotLabel -> "Histogram of Dataset 1"]
```

[image]

I would like to reproduce the shading (as per the years) in this histogram: i.e. between 1997 and 2002, no background shading; between 2002 and 2005, very light shading; between 20005 and 2010, darker shading. I have searched the documentation for `Histogram3D` and elsewhere to no avail. Can something like this be achieved in *Mathematica* or do I need to do post-processing elsewhere?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Is this what you mean? I put different colors in the background, to make clear what I added:

```
Show[Histogram3D[dataHistogramSet, FaceGrids -> {Bottom, Front, Left},
   ChartStyle -> "GrayTones", ViewPoint -> {2.78, 1.3, 1.43}, 
  PlotLabel -> "Histogram of Dataset 1"],
 Graphics3D[
  Translate[{EdgeForm[],
    {Red, 
     Polygon[{{1995, 0, 0}, {1995, 0, 100}, {2002, 0, 100}, {2002, 0, 
        0}, {2002, 300, 0}, {1995, 300, 0}}]}, {Orange, 
     Polygon[{{2002, 0, 0}, {2002, 0, 100}, {2005, 0, 100}, {2005, 0, 
        0}, {2005, 300, 0}, {2002, 300, 0}}]}, {Yellow, 
     Polygon[{{2005, 0, 0}, {2005, 0, 100}, {2010, 0, 100}, {2010, 0, 
        0}, {2010, 300, 0}, {2005, 300, 0}}]}}, {0, -3, -3}]]
 ]
```

[image: histogram]!

Comment: This is great - I was also hoping to get the background to also extend along the 'floor' of the chart too. Apologies for not being so specific - and thanks for providing this, I'll read up on these docs.

Comment: OK - the trick here is to figure out what the x, y and z axis of the plot are, and then draw polygons in the same way that you probably did with your 2D example. So for the floor coloring, you'd need to make the polygons vary in the first and second coordinate, leaving the third one at 0.

Comment: Ok, let me give it a try. With the first plots, I cheated with the 'drawing tools,' which are not enabled for `Historgram3D` apparently.

Comment: I had another suggestion - offset the background a little to avoid intersections with the histogram bars. I'll just add that to my answer and put in the additional polygon corners.

Answer (score 11):

I'm sure you'll get more sensible answers, but here's some `FaceGrid` abuse:

```
Histogram3D[dataHistogramSet, 
 FaceGrids -> 
  With[{abuse = 
     Table[{k, LightGray}, {k, 2002, 2005, 0.01}]~Join~
      Table[{k, Gray}, {k, 2005, 2010, 0.01}]},
   {{Front, {abuse, None}}, {Bottom, {abuse, None}}, Left}], 
 ChartStyle -> "GrayTones", ViewPoint -> {2.78, 1.3, 1.43}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Histogram of Dataset 1"]
```

[image: Facegrid abuse]

Comment: (+1) Could it be that your uploaded image isn't quite right? The overhanging bars on the left look wrong - and  when I try your code the problem isn't there.

Comment: @Jens It's what I get with that data.  My version gives a histogram with a bin stretching from 2010 to 2011.

Comment: Ah, I think you must have been using an earlier edit of the data file... when I looked, there was no 2011 data. It's not important - just looked confusing.

Comment: There's no 2011 data in what I was using, it's just where it decides the bin should be.

Comment: Hmm, does that mean it's a version-dependent difference? I have MMA version 8.0.4 and see the bins ending with 2010. Strange.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a solid variation of Jens' method that may prove useful.  It is also somewhat more concise.

```
Show[
  Histogram3D[dataHistogramSet, FaceGrids -> {Bottom, Front, Left},
   ChartStyle -> "GrayTones", PlotLabel -> "Histogram of Dataset 1"], 
  Graphics3D[
   Translate[{EdgeForm[], Opacity[0.1],
    {Red,    Cuboid[{{1995, 0, 0}, {2002, 300, 100}}]},
    {Orange, Cuboid[{{2002, 0, 0}, {2005, 300, 100}}]},
    {Yellow, Cuboid[{{2005, 0, 0}, {2010, 300, 100}}]}}, {0, -3, -3}]]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: It shows what `Show` can do that the built-in plot options can't.

Answer (score 3):

Divide your data into 3 sets:

{data97to01, data02to05, data06to10}

or whatever years you want to include in each.  Then it goes pretty simply:

```
Histogram3D[{data97to01, data02to05, data06to10}, 
 FaceGrids -> {Bottom, Front, Left}, 
 ChartStyle -> {Darker[Gray], Gray, White}, 
 ViewPoint -> {2.78, 1.3, 1.43}, PlotLabel -> "Histogram of Dataset"]
```

[image]